# Comparison of two means when they are means of means?

Tags: mean, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two vectors "$A$" and "$B$". Each vector contains multiple mean values derived from observations. The two vectors are subsets of a sample that has been categorized into five vectors. All vectors have different lengths.

I would like to compare the mean values of vectors "$A$" and "$B$" to see whether they are statistically different from each other. The test I am using is the Wilcoxon rank-sum statistic.

**Question:** Which approach is correct (or neither)?

1. Compare the mean values in vectors "$A$" and "$B$" to assess whether they are statistically different. Since the items in the vector are means, the test would appear to be a comparison between "mean of means".
2. Decompose the mean values in vectors "$A$" and "$B$" into observations that make up the mean, then compare the individual observations of vectors "$A$" and "$B$".